# Changing BLE Advertisement Data on Runtime for iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Short version: Is it possible to dynamically change the advertisement data of an iOS device during run-time?

Long version: Ok, so here is the specific scenario: I have a BLE device scanning for advertisements, and number of devices that are advertising. Based on the received advertisement packets the central device, who is scanning, will open a lock. Now, I know that the advertisement packets can be copied by other devices; hence, authenticating the correct devices is an issue.

Our solution is to change the advertisement packets every now and then (say every minute) in a way that only the authenticated devices and the central device knows the pattern. However, in order to do this we need to be able to change our advertisement data dynamically.

I know that I can do this with BLE MCUs and I am fairly certain this is possible with Android devices since changing Advertisement data is allowed. Is this possible with iOS devices as well, i.e. can I dynamically change the advertisement data of an iOS device during run-time?

P.S. An easier solution would be to establish a connection, but I am also not certain if an iOS device can establish a connection when the application is in the Background?

Comment: I suggest you read Apple's [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) this goes into detail about what operations are possible while your app is in foreground and background. It even has specific examples for a BLE lock.

Comment: Also, your 'data through changing the advertising packet' approach sounds fragile (varying advertisement windows etc.), I would be concerned whether it could provide the performance users will expect from a lock, especially in noisy BT environments. I believe other BLE locks on the market make connections from app to lock.

Comment: Through my research, I have seen many BLE locks that work with connections; and as I have also explained I think that is the easier and safer option. However, there is a difference between the application that we want to build and the application that those locks present. We want the users to simply walk to the door and open it without the need for entering a password for instance. Hence, we cannot use the phone in central mode, and this has to be achieved while the app is in the background. We are simply investigating the possibility of such application.

Comment: As for the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide, I know that advertisement is possible while the App is in Background, but it does not explain, as far as I can tell, whether you can change this advertisement data. Also, the iOS shutting down the application is a major problem for the application. Thus, I think we need to find another way for our application. Any insights are appreciated. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @mtlh I have a similar problem to solve. any luck so far?